# Why does Incanter return number instead of sequence when result is one value?

Tags: clojure, incanter

I am having an issue that can be reduced to the following problem: When the result of a query is one value, `sel / $` returns a number, when it is more than one value, it is a sequence:

```
(with-data (to-dataset [[1 2] [3 4]])
    ($ :col-1))
```

yields (2 4), but

```
(with-data (to-dataset [[1 2]])
    ($ :col-1))
```

yields 2.

I would like it to be a sequence at all times, since I want to e. g. apply + to the sequence.  I want to avoid checking for the type using (seq?). Any ideas? Is this behaviour of Incanter reasonable?

This is my workaround:

```
(let [seq-it (fn [a] (if (seq? a) a (list a)))]
  (with-data (to-dataset [[1 2]])
    (->> ($ :col-1) 
         (seq-it))))
```

which yields (2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a bug in Incanter (or you might regard it as a serious design flaw that should be fixed).

It is probably related to the issue discussed here, where 1x1 matrix results get converted to doubles:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/incanter/89RNomNMBWA

Comment: If this is a bug or design flaw, I could use

(let [seq-it (fn [a] (if (seq? a) a (list a)))]
 (with-data (to-dataset [[1 2] [3 4]])
   (->> ($ :col-1)
        (seq-it))))