# Why does Incanter lose column title when only querying one column?

Tags: clojure, incanter

When selecting two columns from a dataset, the result has the two given column titles as expected. But when only specifying one column, the one resulting column loses it's title, instead, it is titled "0":

This makes it hard to use $order or whatever in later steps that take column names.

That is, this will work

```
(with-data data   
  (->> ($ [:foo :bar])
       ($order [:foo] :asc)
       (view)))
```

and this will fail

```
(with-data data
  (->> ($ [:foo])
       ($order [:foo] :asc)
       (view)))
```

Any ideas what is going wrong or what to do?

Comment: Could you include a bit of `data` and an snip of the output in each case?

Comment: Hang on, I think I see what is happening: Incanter returns `incanter.core.Dataset` in the two-column example and `clojure.lang.LazySeq` in the one-column example. This reminds me of ["Why does Incanter return number instead of sequence when result is one value?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16385215/). I can provide data if you still like, but maybe this already helps?

Comment: Even minimal sample data will work, just use `(def data (dataset [:foo :bar] [[:a :b] [:c :d]]))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

which version of Incanter are you using? This behavior was changed in recent versions, and at least 1.5.4 works correctly.  But take into account that behavior of `$` is different when you pass the column name as single element, and as vector:

```
incanter.main=> (def data (dataset [:foo :bar] [[:a :b] [:c :d]]))
#'incanter.main/data
incanter.main=> ($ :foo data)
(:a :c)
incanter.main=> ($ [:foo] data)

| :foo |
|------|
|   :a |
|   :c |
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you hit on the correct answer when you point out that in the single key case incanter simply returns a sequence. One way to get around this, though it could be a little less elegant is to simply request a second column and ignore the second result or put it into a sequence of maps after. Something only a little hackish like:

```
(map hash-map (repeat :key) result-seq)
```